# Configure Sonar to exclude files from Maven pom.xml

Tags: java, xml, maven, sonarqube

I have a project configured in maven and the code analysis is done by SonarQube.

I am trying to configure SonarQube in the pom.xml file to exclude a few files from the code analysis. Those files can be identified by their class names, they contain the underscore character before the extension (they are metamodel classes). Below I give the part of the pom.xml file where I try to exclude them:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <sonar.sources>src/main/java</sonar.sources>
        <sonar.exclusions>file:**/src/main/java/**/*_.*</sonar.exclusions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

However, the above code does not work. Is there a way to configure SonarQube from my pom.xml file to ignore those files when analysing the source code?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: SonarQube config parameters are treated as "System properties" if I remember correctly. Have you tried setting them as global <properties> in the pom.xml?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Sonar exclusions (like other sonar properties) [have to be added to the `<properties>` section](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreFiles) of the POM file. Like so (example from excluding jOOQ autogenerated code from current project):

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <sonar.host.url>http://www.example.com/</sonar.host.url>
    <sonar.jdbc.url>jdbc:postgresql://www.example.com/sonar</sonar.jdbc.url>
    <sonar.jdbc.driver>org.postgresql.Driver</sonar.jdbc.driver>
    <sonar.jdbc.username>sonar</sonar.jdbc.username>
    <sonar.jdbc.password>sonar</sonar.jdbc.password>
    <sonar.exclusions>org/binarytherapy/generated/**/*, **/GuiceBindComposer.java</sonar.exclusions>
    <sonar.dynamic>reuseReports</sonar.dynamic>
</properties>
```

Comment: what is the best option to specify many exclusions as the string is getting pretty long very quickly?

Comment: You can put it on multiple lines; just have a linebreak after each comma.

Comment: <sonar.exclusions>com/vedant/pt/request/*.java</sonar.exclusions>  I added this into pom properties and its not excluding classes under this package. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: If you want to exclude all classes under the package you should probably do ```/**/*``` like in my example. You can read more about Ant style path matching here: https://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html

Comment: @MikkelLøkke - Is there any way we can disable perticular rule in `pom.xml` file ? I cant go & disable in sonar as its used at org level.

Comment: seems jacoco exclusion isn't enough for sonar report coverage exclusion.

Answer (score 44):

classes/packages mentioned in `<sonar.exclusions>` excludes the given classes from all static analysis by Sonar, however `<sonar.coverage.exclusions>` excludes given classes/packages only from coverage, and still be analyzed for other parameters.

```
<properties>
    <sonar.coverage.exclusions>
        **/domain/**/*,
        **/pojos/*
    </sonar.coverage.exclusions>
</properties>
```

Reference:

- https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters#AnalysisParameters-Exclusions/Inclusions

Source:

- https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreCodeCoverage
- https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters#AnalysisParameters-Exclusions/Inclusions
- https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforMaven-ExcludingamodulefromSonarQubeanalysis

Comment: Within version 6.5 there is a bug if your add a new line between each entry. Please see https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-9666

Comment: Just noting that <sonar.exclusions> will exclude matched files from all static analysis and code coverage. Also, the commas are required between multiple matchers.

Comment: just to confirm that this works with JaCoCo version 0.8.6 and SonarQube version 9.0.1

Comment: `<sonar.coverage.exclusions>` was confusing, spent hours trying to figure out what exactly it was doing. Its behavior was inconsistent too in my experimentation. `<sonar.exclusions>` is what I was looking after, thanks!

Answer (score 16):

When doing your Sonar exclusions as shown in the accepted answer, make sure you follow this pattern approach from the [SonarQube documentation](https://docs.sonarcloud.io/advanced-setup/analysis-scope/#where-to-configure-the-settings):

> Relative paths are based on the fully qualified name of the component (like the one displayed below):

```
src/main/java/org/sonar/batch/phases/AbstractPhaseEvent.java
```

**Examples**:

```
# Exclude all classes ending with "Bean"
# Matches org/sonar.api/MyBean.java, org/sonar/util/MyOtherBean.java, etc.
**/*Bean.java

# Exclude all classes in the "src/main/java/org/sonar" directory
# Matches src/main/java/org/sonar/MyClass.java, src/main/java/org/sonar/MyOtherClass.java
# But does not match src/main/java/org/sonar/util/MyClassUtil.java
src/main/java/org/sonar/*

# Exclude all files in the "bank" directory and its sub-directories
# Matches bank/ZTR00021.cbl, bank/data/CBR00354.cbl, bank/data/REM012345.cob
bank/**/*

# Exclude all COBOL programs in the "bank" directory and its sub-directories whose extension is .cbl
# Matches bank/ZTR00021.cbl, bank/data/CBR00354.cbl
bank/**/*.cbl
```

So if you want to exclude all classes ending with "Bean" and all classes in the "src/main/java/org/sonar" directory (but not in its sub-directories) add the following `sonar.exclusions` property to the pom's `properties`:

```
<properties>
  ...
  <sonar.exclusions>**/*Bean.java,src/main/java/org/sonar/*</sonar.exclusions>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 5):

**There are three ways to do.**

1. You can add these files to the properties in your pom.xml:
   This one is to exclude from code duplication:

```
<properties>
    <sonar.cpd.exclusions>
        **/dto/**/*,
        **/entity/**/*
    </sonar.cpd.exclusions>
</properties>
```

2. Using pom.xml
   We can also define exclusion rules in the pom.xml file using analysis properties.

```
<properties>
<sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria>e1</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria>
    <sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.ruleKey>
        java:S4784
    </sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.ruleKey>
    <sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.resourceKey>
        **/commons/**/*
    </sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.resourceKey>
</properties>
```

3. Using sonar-project.properties
   We can also define exclusion rules in the `sonar-project.properties file` using analysis
   properties.Let's define and add the `sonar-project.properties file` to our resource dir:

```
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria=e1
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.ruleKey=java:S106
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.resourceKey=**/SonarExclude.java
```

[how we can see the rule Key from sonarqube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2kUH.png)

Answer (score 0):

> We have to add below code in maven settings.xml file

```
       <profile>
                <id>sonar</id>
                <activation>
                    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
                </activation>     
           <properties>
               <sonar.host.url>http://localhost:9000</sonar.host.url>

               <sonar.exclusions>
               # exclude more class under same package
                  src/main/java/co/domain/*,
                  src/main/java/co/util/JsonMapper.java

               # exclude individual class
                  src/main/java/co/util/ProviderCallBuilder.java
               </sonar.exclusions>
            </properties>
       </profile>
```

Comment: Hi Deep, welcome. Please consider adding more information.

Answer (score 0):

An addition to the answer of @Yatindra Soni (unfortunately I have not yet enough reputation to comment your answer):

If you want to exclude multiple sonar rules by pom.xml, you have to specify

```
<sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria>e1,e2,e3</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria>
```

only once and comma separate the values

```
<properties>
    <sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria>e1,e2,e3</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria>
    
    <!-- rule e1 -->
    <sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.ruleKey>
        java:S4784
    </sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.ruleKey>
    <sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.resourceKey>
        **/commons/**/*
    </sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.resourceKey>
    
    <!-- rule e2 -->
    <sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.ruleKey>
        java:S2899
    </sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.ruleKey>
    <sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.resourceKey>
        **/entity/**/*
    </sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.resourceKey>
    
    <!-- rule e3 -->
    <sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.ruleKey>
        java:S3358
    </sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.ruleKey>
    <sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.resourceKey>
        **/*.java
    </sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.resourceKey>
</properties>
```

Answer (score -4):

I was using sonar to analyse **PHP** code base. 
Both `<sonar.exclusions>` and `<sonar.coverage.exclusions>` didn't do the trick.
My solution is - Instead of specifying the exclusions, I ended up specifying the inclusion directories as below:

```
<properties>
  .........
  <sonar.exclusions>./app/models,./app/controllers</sonar.exclusions>
  .........
</properties>
```