# sonar-maven-plugin: Can not set sonar.sources src/main/resources

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, pom.xml, sonar-maven-plugin

I have a problem with maven-sonar settings. I need to include all my project files at *src/main/java* and *src/main/resources* so that SonarQube will show results of all my files but exclude some files in *src/main/resources/static/file*. For test path it is already set by default at *src/test/java*

This is How i set my POM.XML

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->

    <!-- Sonar static analysis / Jacoco code coverage -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <start-class>com.Example.wp.WpCoreApplication</start-class>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <sonar.sources>src/main/java, src/main/resources</sonar.sources>
    <sonar.exclusions>src/main/resources/static/file</sonar.exclusions>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId> 
        </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.debatty</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-string-similarity</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.11</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                        <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                        <version>2.19.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>${jacoco.agent.argLine}</argLine>
                    <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.7.201606060606</version>
            <configuration>
                <dataFile>target/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <propertyName>jacoco.agent.argLine</propertyName>
                        <destFile>target/jacoco.exec</destFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>jacoco-report</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>rpm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1-alpha-3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-rpm</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>attached-rpm</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

But when I run my maven-sonar with command prompt: *mvn sonar:sonar* . There is error log like this

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.865 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-11-28T14:46:40+07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 68M/449M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:
3.1.1:sonar (default-cli) on project wp: The directory 'D:\PROJECT\wp-core\
src\main\resources' does not exist for Maven module com.sample:wp:jar:0.1.26. Pleas
e check the property sonar.sources -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
xception
```

How I can setup sonar so that It can scan all my files? I already look at [documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters) and this [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21425012/configure-sonar-to-exclude-files-from-maven-pom-xml)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably remove the extra space. Change

```
<sonar.sources>src/main/java, src/main/resources</sonar.sources>
```

to

```
<sonar.sources>src/main/java,src/main/resources</sonar.sources>
```

Comment: If this is the solution you probably should improve the `sonar-maven-plugin` ;-)

Comment: Ahh.. this is quite tricky, when I check it, I found the path has "space"..
I think they need to improve sonar-maven-plugin like @FrVaBe said.

Comment: @David Vincent - Nevertheless if removing the space resolved your problem you should accept (and probably upvote) the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Only below specified entries related to sonar are required by sonarQube for static code analysis.

Under the properties tag in your pom.xml, add only following entries related to sonar: You can  property. By default sonar will scal all files placed under src folder.

```
    <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
    <sonar.exclusions>
        **/static/file/**
    </sonar.exclusions>
```

Under the plugins tag in your pom.xml, replace your maven-surefire-plugin and jacoco-maven-plugin entries with following entries:

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.13</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.2.201409121644</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Lets not add all those parameters which are actually not required by sonar for static code analysis.
            You will see that, I have added only  and  property in properties tag.
            The correct syntax to use  is not to use src/main/ this type of path. If you specify src/main in sonar.exclusions then sonar will not exclude files from static code analysis.
            I faced this issue in my project.

Let me know if it still you face some issues.

Comment: After read your post, I found my mistake. I just need to write <sonar.sources>src/main</sonar.sources> and its works.
I don't know why I can't specify it each path like my settings.

Comment: Btw, Im not using your maven-surefire-plugin and jacoco-maven-plugin settings, but it still work. I only read the End Summary that you wrote, and I suddenly understand my mistake.
Thank you @Reena

Comment: maybe you can edit your answer, and add <sonar.sources>src/main</sonar.sources>
Because after read your explanation, I just need to change my setting like that and it works like magic. ahaha. Thank you :)